# WPF Custom Effect disappears when using Remote Desktop

Tags: wpf, remote-desktop, pixel-shader

I currently have an issue that removes my effect from the UIElement in question when using Remote Desktop (I've tried various types of clients).
RemoteFX is enabled on the host Machine (windows 7 and 8/8.1)
The PixelShader i made is compiled to ps_3_0

```
this.Effect = customShader; // this doesn't work on RDP
this.Effect = new BlurEffect(); // this works on RDP
```

Does anyone know anything about losing Effects when viewing from RDP client?
TeamViewer and other remote access services work fine.

Comment: This is probably Remote Desktop trying to improve performance by preventing effects on the client. It's probably a feature, as opposed to a bug. Check on the remote desktop forums/documentation for a way of disabling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue - somehow compiling to ps_3_0 would not let me see the shader effect on RDP.

Compile your PixelShader to ps_2_0 and it should work.

*Edit: After further investigation - i found out that PixelShader 3.0 does not support "Software Mode" as opposed to PixelShader 2.0 which does - and that is why it won't work over RDP. WPF Does currently not support using shaders above 3.0 so I am forced to revert back to version 2.0*

Comment: It's been a few years now but thanks to the pandemic, a lot of people are now using RDP. I wonder if there's any update from Microsoft for PixelShader.